# How to hide Match All and Any radio option in af:query panel in adf

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We are calling DC method directly, please check the highlighted portion in [snapshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLeho.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `displayMode` attribute of `af:query` element to compact. Match Type will be rendered in footer which is hidden by default.
For more info check the `displayMode` attribute description in [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E12419_09/tagdoc/af_query.html) in Attributes table.